# Is there any implementation of a MergeIterator?

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons-collection

Does any of the existing collection libraries (guava, commons-collection) provide a MergeIterator that's constructed with:

```
MergeIterator(Iterator<Comparable> iters...)
```

and then (assuming the source iterators are sorted) advances through the iterators in parallel and returns the elements in order?

```
[1,3,5] + [2,8] => [1,2,3,5,8]
```

This would be a fun class to write, but I wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Iterators.mergeSorted`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#mergeSorted%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.util.Comparator%29) in Guava is such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CollatingIterator of commons-collections:

```
 List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5);
 List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(2, 8);

 Iterator<Integer> merged =
    IteratorUtils.collatedIterator(ComparatorUtils.NATURAL_COMPARATOR,
                                   list1.iterator(), list2.iterator());

 System.out.println(IteratorUtils.toList(merged));
```

This will print the following:

```
 [1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```